# Форматирование строки с помощью регулярного выражения

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, строки

Имеется строка в примерно таком виде (кавычками указал границы строки):

> "Это строка . Это строка...Это строка. "

Хочу на выходе получить такое:

> "Это строка. Это строка... Это строка."

Раньше использовал приблизительно такой код для замены символа точки:

`replace("\\s*\\.\\s*", ". ");`

Подход не гибкий и в целом мне не нравиться, для примера в конце строки пробел был не нужен. Поэтому ищу новые пути решения. Нужно сначало удалить все пробелы до и после точки(или троеточия) и добавить пробел после данных знаков. Посоветуйте решение.

Comment: `s.replaceAll("\\s*(\\.+)\\s*", "$1 ").trim()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете использовать

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\s*(\\.+)\\s*", "$1 ").trim();
```

**Подробности**

- `\s*` - ноль и более пробельных символов
- `(\.+)` - Захватывающая подмаска №1 (`$1` в шаблоне замены ссылается на значение этой подмаски): одна и более точек
- `\s*` - ноль и более пробельных символов.

[Java-демо](https://ideone.com/tJQggq):

```
String s = "Это строка . Это строка...Это строка. ";
System.out.println("'" + s.replaceAll("\\s*(\\.+)\\s*", "$1 ").trim() + "'");
// => 'Это строка. Это строка... Это строка.'
```

Comment: Могу ли я использовать оператор ИЛИ в этом выражении, что бы работать не только с точкой а и с запятой, многоточием и т.д?Пробовал так: "\\s*(\\.+|\\.{3}|,)\\s*" но не выходит.

Comment: @UjinUkr [Всё работает](https://regex101.com/r/2A9mqy/1). Приведите пример строки + ожидаемый результат.

Comment: Была моя ошибка, спасибо)

Comment: хотелось бы узнать можно ли создать еще одну маску для других символов и не добавлять к нему пробел в этом же выражении, что то вроде "$1 $2"?

Comment: @UjinUkr Можно.

Comment: Тогда как указать в регулярное выражении еще одну маску?для примера указать знак апострофа, для которого пробелы не нужны."\\s*(\\.+|,+|\\.{3})\\s*\\s*('+)\\s*" Не понимаю как условия связать.

Comment: @UjinUkr Приведите пример строки + ожидаемый результат. Кстати, `(\\.+|,+|\\.{3})` = `(\\.+|,+)`, `\\.+` уже отлавливает все троеточия.

Comment: Для примера "Это ст ' рока ...Это стр 'ока", где для апострофа не нужны пробелы, а для точек и многоточий нужны: "Это ст'рока... Это стр'ока".

Comment: @UjinUkr Это [возможно только с помощью более трудного выражения + `Matcher.appendReplacement()`](https://ideone.com/U3ZdCA). Дело в том, что пробел добавляется в шаблоне *замены*, а регулярки в Java не поддерживают условий, альтернатив, в шаблонах замены.